# GWT parse date in different locales

Tags: java, date, gwt

I have date from server, represented by string like `"Thu Oct 31 2013 00:00:00 GMT+0200"` and i have to parse it in `Date` object. I use `DateTimeFormat` class for operations with dates.

The problem is that i can parse it only in English locale. In any other locale i will get `IllegalArgumentException` from parse method and i can't set right locale exactly for parsing.

How can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to know the pattern and create a instance for every locale/pattern you want to try:

[How to convert String of datetime to date using GWT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11342670/how-to-convert-string-of-datetime-to-date-using-gwt)

Comment: The pattern is "EEE MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss 'GMT'z". Problem is in representing this format in different languages. I get string in english in all locales and i have to parse it in english. In other locales i get parse error

Comment: If the input string is in another locale, you will need another pattern to parse the different string.