# Not able to convert the String to Date in GWT

Tags: java, date, gwt

I am trying to change a String to Date in GWT.After Searching in StackOverFlow, I got one solution.But still I am  getting

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Fri Feb 21 00:00:00 IST 2014

Below is my code in GXT GridEditor class.

```
DateTimeFormat fmt = DateTimeFormat.getFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy");
Date checkInDate = fmt.parse(ACCCheckBoxModel.getSelectedItem().getCheckinDate());
```

From `ACCCheckBoxModel.getSelectedItem().getCheckinDate()` I am getting a String. I need to convert this String to Date. And then I need to convert the Date format to `dd/MMM/yyyy` format.

Please suggest how to resolve this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to convert String of datetime to date using GWT?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11342670/how-to-convert-string-of-datetime-to-date-using-gwt)

Comment: @Jigar Joshi I am already look into this. Before posting this question. But still not able to parse.

Comment: can you post exact code that doesn't work for you

Comment: @JigarJoshi Please find the code in the question.

Answer (score 1):

The parser does not understand IST. Try to move parsing to the server side.

Following citation from [API-Doc](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/i18n/client/DateTimeFormat.html):

> The time zone support for parsing is limited. Only standard GMT and
>   RFC format are supported. Time zone specification using time zone id
>   (like America/Los_Angeles), time zone names (like PST, Pacific
>   Standard Time) are not supported. Normally, it is too much a burden
>   for a client application to load all the time zone symbols. And in
>   almost all those cases, it is a better choice to do such parsing on
>   server side through certain RPC mechanism. This decision is based on
>   particular use cases we have studied; in principle, it could be
>   changed in future versions.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with `IST` that doesn't converted by `DateTimeFormat`

Try this one, Its working fine without `IST` in pattern

```
    DateTimeFormat fmt = DateTimeFormat.getFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss yyyy");
    Date checkInDate = fmt.parse("Fri Feb 21 00:00:00 2014");
    System.out.println(DateTimeFormat.getFormat("dd/MMM/yyyy").format(checkInDate));
```

or use `GMT` in place of `IST` as shown below

```
    DateTimeFormat fmt = DateTimeFormat.getFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss v yyyy");
    Date checkInDate = fmt.parse("Fri Feb 21 00:00:00 GMT+05:30 2014");
    System.out.println(DateTimeFormat.getFormat("dd/MMM/yyyy").format(checkInDate));
```

---

Simply call a GWT RPC call and at server try below code to find out your localized date format and use it now.

```
        Locale locale = httpServletRequest.getLocale();

        final Date currentDate = new Date();
        final DateFormat dateInstance = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.FULL, locale);
        final String format = dateInstance.format(currentDate);
        System.out.println(format);

        if (dateInstance instanceof SimpleDateFormat) {
            System.out.println("pattern: " + ((SimpleDateFormat) dateInstance).toPattern());
            System.out.println("localized pattern: "+((SimpleDateFormat) dateInstance).toLocalizedPattern());
        }
```

Here is the sample code about date pattern at [internationalization sample](http://gwt.googleusercontent.com/samples/I18N/I18N.html)

Here is one more link to read about [How to get the pattern of Number Format of a specific locale?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22513607/how-to-get-the-pattern-of-number-format-of-a-specific-locale) at server side.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
String string = "January 2, 2010";
Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM d, yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH).parse(string);
System.out.println(date); // Sat Jan 02 00:00:00 BOT 2010
```

and take a look at

[Java string to date conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4216745/java-string-to-date-conversion)